# writing (partially) NULL record in postgresql table as part of the try / exept using python client

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, psycopg2

I have a table in Postgresql with postgis extension installed. Columns are a mixbag of data types:
we varchar, some text, some int, some one-dimensional arrays, and also some geometry types.

I am using a python client to connect to DB. I have a function that attempts to insert a record into that table. On the insert attempt, if I get an exception, I want to have another go, but this time I just want to insert a few first columns and the rest with the NULL values. How to do that in the best way?

I have the code like this:

```py
try: 
    # attempt to insert record is here

except:
    logging.error(f".ERROR inserting record {record_for_db[0]} to table {table_name}:")
    logging.error(str(sys.exc_info()))
    conn.rollback()

    try:
        placeholders = sql.SQL(', ').join(
            sql.Placeholder() if i < 4 else sql.SQL('NULL::{}').format(sql.Identifier('geometry').as_string(conn))
            for i in range(len(table_columns))
        )

        query = sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({}) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING").format(
            sql.Identifier(table_name),
            sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Identifier(column) for column in table_columns),
            placeholders
        )

        values = record_for_db[:4] + (None,) * (len(table_columns) - 4)
        # test print during dev
        logging.info("..values: " + str(values))

        with conn.cursor() as single_cursor:
            single_cursor.execute(query.as_string(conn), values)
            conn.commit()

    except:
        logging.error(f"..ERROR inserting placeholder record {record_for_db[0]} to table {table_name}:")
        logging.error(str(sys.exc_info()))
        conn.rollback()
```

but I get the following error:

```
(<class 'TypeError'>, TypeError('Composed elements must be Composable, got \'"geometry"\' instead'), <traceback object at 0x000001E95A71EB40>
```

So I guess something is wrong about one of the NULL values I am trying to insert in one of the columns. Later, I adjusted the code to something like this (as per the dear chat gpt advice ;) ) - I am trying to have a code which would dynamically check the columns type and suggest relevant NULL value:

```py
# Execute a SELECT query to fetch a single row
select_query = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {} LIMIT 1").format(sql.Identifier(table_name))
cursor.execute(select_query.as_string(conn))
result = cursor.fetchone()

# Get the column types from cursor.description
column_types = [desc[1].type_code for desc in cursor.description]

# Construct the placeholders dynamically based on column types
placeholders = sql.SQL(', ').join(
    sql.Placeholder() if i < 4 else (
        sql.SQL('NULL') if column_types[i] == psycopg2.extensions.ARRAY else
        sql.SQL('NULL::{}').format(sql.Identifier('geometry')) if column_types[i] == psycopg2.extensions.STRING else
        sql.Placeholder()
    )
    for i in range(len(table_columns))
)

# Construct the INSERT query
query = sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({}) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING").format(
    sql.Identifier(table_name),
    sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Identifier(column) for column in table_columns),
    placeholders
)

values = record_for_db[:4] + (None,) * (len(table_columns) - 4)
logging.info("..values: " + str(values))
logging.info("..query: " + str(query.as_string(conn)))

with conn.cursor() as single_cursor:
    single_cursor.execute(query.as_string(conn), values)
    conn.commit()
```

however this is also returning errors complaining that `(<class 'AttributeError'>, AttributeError("module 'psycopg2.extensions' has no attribute 'ARRAY'"), <traceback object at 0x000001A34A715680>)`. Any suggestions for avenues to explore? Or does anyone by any chance have a (similar) code for handling such scenario?

Comment: 1) Per here [Extensions ARRAYs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.BINARYARRAY) there is no `psycopg2.extensions.ARRAY` as the traceback states. 2) Why are you doing this? Just have generic placeholders for all the fields and retry the INSERT with `None(Null)` parameters.

Comment: trying what you suggest is actually where I started.. If I do this I get:
`TypeError: Composed elements must be Composable, got None instead` - I guess this is because I have some columns in Posgres that are arrays?

Comment: You will need to show the code you used as update to your question.